# Compare Server Time and Browser Time

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My table that has 3 columns: `FileName`, `LastUpdateTime`, and a Restart button.

I need to display the restart button only if the last update time is more than 20 min ago. I get the last update time from the server. `d = new Date()` gives the local browser time but the lastUpdateTime is coming from the server.  Server is in the different time zone than the clients browser.

The following code works if both server and browser are in the same time zone. Do you have any suggestions on how solve this if the server and browser are in a different time zone?

This application supposed to run anywhere in US and Europe.

```
var lastUpdatedTime = (gridData[i].LastTimeUpdated);
var d = new Date();
//deducting 20 min from current time
var deductTwenty = d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - 20); 
var parsedupdatetime = Date.parse(lastUpdatedTime);                          

// If the last update time is not 20 ago, hide it. 
if (parsedupdatetime > deductTwenty) {
    newrestartButton.hide();
}
```

Comment: What is the format of `LastTimeUpdated`?

Comment: Have the server report UTC time. Then do calculations on the browser also in UTC time -- No worries about timezone differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .NET in your .cshtml file to get the date server-side. Assuming you use MVC (since you tagged this question kendo-asp.net-mvc).

```
@{
    var deductTwenty = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-20);
}

<script>
    var jsDeductTwenty = new Date(@deductTwenty.Year, @deductTwenty.Month-1, @deductTwenty.Day, @deductTwenty.Hour, @deductTwenty.Minute);
</script>
```

Result:

[image: JS Time]

Comment: I get syntax error after every comma when I pass year, month etc as a parameter. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Not sure why that'd happen, it works in my test app.

Comment: It worked, I get the server side date. but I still get these warning signal in the visual studio. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What's probably going wrong is the server date parsing. Take a look at the [Date.parse function spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) - and make sure your server is returning something that will get parsed correctly like an ISO8601 formatted date.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your `lastUpdatedTime` with client timezone, means you should convert server time to client time when subtracting date with 20 mins. You can use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/), [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) and [jstimezonedetect](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect) to achieve this.

Your code should be like this

```
// get current client timezone with jstimezonedetect
var currentTz = jstz.determine().name(); // e.g "Europe/London"

// parse last update time to moment object and change its timezone
var lastUpdateTime = moment(lastUpdatedTime, "M/DD/YYYY hh:mm a").tz(currentTz);

// create date using moment and deduct 20 mins from it
var deductTwenty = moment().subtract(20, 'minutes');                     

// now compare
if (lastUpdateTime > deductTwenty) {
    newrestartButton.hide();
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I already used the one suggested by @Nicholas. I like this approach too. I will keep this in my mind for the future implementations.